# ASP.NET "pass through" WEB API

Tags: asp.net, json, .net, api, rest

I am currently working with an architecture which consists of two connected APIs: an *External API* exposed to clients and an *Internal API* which connects to internal services and is only exposed to the *External API*.

The *External API* should be passing through the response data from the *Internal API* to the client, without processing, but I couldn't figure out to do this. I'm currently deserializing and serializing the objects again.

This is only an issue because for big json payloads (bigger than 15MB) the *External API* starts adding some considerable processing time, which is from the json deserialize method alone.

Is there a way to return a json result based on the request, without processing it?

Current code simplified for brevity:

**External API Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSomeData(...)
{
    var serviceResponse = await _serviceInvoker.GetAsync<SomeType>(...)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
   
    Response.StatusCode = (int)serviceResponse.StatusCode;
   
    return new JsonResult(serviceResponse.Content);
}
```

**Internal service invoker response parser**

```
using System.Text.Json;

private async Task<ServiceInvokerResult> ParseServiceResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    object deserializedContent = null;
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

    switch (response.StatusCode)
    {
        case HttpStatusCode.OK:
                deserializedContent = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(content);
            break;
        (...)
    }

    return new ServiceInvokerResult
    {
        (...)
        StatusCode = response.StatusCode,
        Content = deserializedContent ?? content
    };
}
```

***///***

***Solution update based on responses:***

The *ServiceInvoker* now always returns a *HttpResponseMessage* without processing it:

**External API Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSomeData(...)
{
    var serviceResponse = await _serviceInvoker.GetAsync(...)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
   
    Response.StatusCode = (int)serviceResponse.StatusCode;
   
    return new FileStreamResult(await response.GetContentAsStreamAsync(), response.GetContentType());
}
```

**Extension methods**

```
public static async Task<Stream> GetContentAsStreamAsync(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
   return await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

public static string GetContentType(this HttpResponseMessage response)
{
   return response.Content?.Headers?.ContentType?.MediaType ?? Constants.Http.JsonContentType;
}
```

Comment: if you're trying to do a pass-thru, you *wouldn't return* a `JsonResult` - you'd simply deal with the secondary response as a stream/pipe, without ever looking at it; perhaps just `return File(response.Content.ReadAsStream(), response.Headers.BlahGetContentType());` (although a custom `ServiceInvokerResult` is valid too; the point is: if you aren't interested in the payload: *don't look at the payload* - just stream it back)

Comment: Thank you, thats it. I would have never considered the FileStream for having File in the name... I actualy have some webmethods where I do return a new File() and where I need to read the content as byte array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tried that personally, but you could try returning a stream of data from your Internal API back to your client.

Make your Internal API return a stream:

```
private async Task<ServiceInvokerResult> ParseServiceResponse<T>(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    var contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    // ...

    return new ServiceInvokerResult
    {
        (...)
        StatusCode = response.StatusCode,
        ContentStream = contentStream,
        ContentType = "application/json"
    };
}
```

Then, in your External API:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSomeData(...)
{
    var response = await _serviceInvoker.GetContentStreamAsync(...)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
   
    // ...
   
    return File(response.ContentStream, response.ContentType);
}
```